# cronjob which backs off during off-peak hours

Tags: cron

I have a php script which crontab executes every 30 minutes, during off-peak hours around 2-7am I don't get much traffic and so I wish to  not run the script during these hours.

I'm not sure how to make a cronjob that will do this as I would find it hard to test.

The cronjob I have at the moment looks like this

```
*/30 * * * *            /usr/bin/php    /var/www/update/inv.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*/30 0-1,8-23 * * *            /usr/bin/php    /var/www/update/inv.php`

the range is inclusive, so 0-1 will do 00:30, 01:30, then 8-23 will do 0830 to 2330

ref: http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html

Comment: Your system must be broken then :)

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict the hours you want the job to run.

```
*/30 0,1,7-23 * * *            /usr/bin/php    /var/www/update/inv.php
```

The times will be every 30 minutes until 0130. It won't run at 0200. The next run will be at 0700 and then every 30 minutes.

There's quite a good article here on how to set up the cron:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: They are equivalent: "0 and 1" = "range between 0 and 1"